# How to use a .NET Framework controller from a .NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have some old controllers in .NET Framework project (4.5.2) and would like to reference them from a .NET Core application (3.0). 
Is there a way to do this?

Referencing controllers from another .NET Core project works just by adding the project to my dependencies and doing this in the Startup.cs.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
       endpoints.MapRazorPages();
   });
```

By referencing I mean when I call a route pointing to an old controller's action, it gets routed to the old controller correctly. i.e. `/Users/Index` on my ASP.NET Core project should point to the `Index` action on the `Users` controller in my ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: What exact version of .Net Framework is the other project targeting?

Comment: It's targeting v4.5.2

Comment: Framework 4.5.2 is only compatable with .Net Standard 1.2, which means .Net Core 1.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: you might be better to do this with rewrite rules at the webserver level

Comment: @tocqueville how did you know the Core project was 3.0?

Comment: It's 3.0. The `app.UseEndpoints` must have given it away.

Comment: @ADyson I am trying to have only the .NET Core project running.

Comment: @dosky that makes no sense. If you want the old controllers to be accessible then the project they are within must be deployed and running. Either that or you have to port them into your new project (and re-write anything which needs re-writing). You can't visit the URL of a controller which isn't running in a webserver.

Comment: @ADyson you can have the controllers in a separate DLL and reference that DLL from a net core app. The question is about whether that DLL containing the controllers can be on net framework or not.

Comment: @tocqueville not really because he's specifically asking for a URL route to point to that action. yes you could include the DLL potentially, but that doesn't make the route available. OP would have to implement shadow controllers in .NET Core with the same routes and then make them call the controller actions from the DLL, get the HTML view string back and render it raw. Which kind of breaks the whole MVC paradigm really. Better to just port the business-logic parts only from the .NET Framework app and re-implement the UI. And accept that the old one stays running till you've ported everything

Comment: @ADyson that's a good suggestion

Comment: @tocqueville And I've never tried, but somehow I suspect it would not be easy to actually instantiate and call the old controller methods as if they were just any old C# class, and get it to behave in the right way. It's not what they're designed for. P.S. even importing any kind of DLL (even business-logic parts) is going to be tricky because of the incompatibility of the versions (not even a good route via re-compiling as .NET Standard). Realistically it's just a gradual re-write job, I think.